# Disinfectant production

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, everyday-chemistry, biochemistry, alcohols

One of my friends says that he made a disinfectant. These are the materials:

- 83% methanol
- isopropyl alcohol
- propylene glycol
- and the others are: citral, geraniol, linalool, dlimonene, l alpha terapineol...

Does this really work? Is this dangerous for health if I use it only for surfaces?

Comment: Methanol is poisonous. While it will evaporate over time this puts methanol vapour in the air, and before it evaporates it is a hazard to touch the surface it is on.

Comment: I think we should nix all disinfectant questions as medical advice.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not a good disinfectant.

To quote from the CDC on chemical disinfectants 'Guideline for Disinfection and Sterilization in Healthcare Facilities (2008)' [available here](https://www.cdc.gov/infectioncontrol/guidelines/disinfection/disinfection-methods/chemical.html):

> Methyl alcohol (methanol) has the weakest bactericidal action of the alcohols and thus seldom is used in healthcare 488.

Comment: i forgot to say, he says he added Colloidal silver to this but i dont know how much.
and he also said one liter of this solvent should be mixed in 200 litters of water, and mixing this much of water with the solvent, make the methanol bad effects to go away, 
now what?